# How to pass variable from component to service in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 components (not parent and child). In my first component I have `partNumber`

```
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {
 @Output() partEvent = new EventEmitter();

 public partNumber: number;
 ngOnInit() {
 this.partNumber = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['part'];
 this.partEvent.emit(this.planetNumber);

   }
}
```

So it works and gives me 1, 2 or 3

And I have second component, where I het data from XML and I need to use `this.partNumber`

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  @Input() planetNumber: string;
  // x2js = new X2JS();
  headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  first = 'assets/first.xml';
  second = 'assets/second.xml';
  third = 'assets/third.xml';

  public x2js = new X2JS();

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  get(): Observable<any> {
      // TODO: pass a URL as a parameter
      return this.http.get(this.first, this.headers).map((res) => res.text());
  }
}
```

What I want to do is something like this

```
      get(): Observable<any> {
        if(this.partNumber === 1){
          return this.http.get(this.first, this.headers).map((res) => res.text());
      } else if(this.partNumber === 2) {
        return this.http.get(this.second, this.headers).map((res) => res.text());
      } else {
        return this.http.get(this.third, this.headers).map((res) => res.text());
      }
}
```

So, if I have 1st part I want to work with first XML, if I have 2nd part - then with second and 3 = third.

I tried to use `@Output`, but it doesn't work, so I guess I missed something.

Comment: You'll probably want to look at using a service to share the same instance of data across components.

Comment: This is exactly what services are for.

Comment: how the `get` method knows `partNumber` value? add the markup HTML

Comment: Ok, I'm really confused here, `DataService` is presumably a service not a component.  Where is `get()` called?

Comment: You can call your service directly in your component and pass your parameter like this : in InfoComponent :  myservice.get(partNumber) . In your code you have actually one service and one component